# Where to find graphics' Drivers for Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 460

Tags: drivers, lenovo, thinkpad, 16.10

I've updated my Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 460 to Ubuntu 16.10, and updated to the latest stable kernel, but the screen keeps having glitches. Especially when watching youtube videos rectangular blocks of a couple of inches in the screen get blurry or fuzzy for a few seconds. It's random and it happens all over the screen. Plus, when I watch Netflix the screen gets cut?? Not sure how to explain it. Like the half bottom of the screen shows the show on normal speed, while the top half sometimes is like catching up?

In short, where can I find the drivers for this specific machine? 
I have gone to Settings > Additional drivers, but nothing's there...

PS: I have no problems when booting to Windows 10.

Edit: I found out that my device uses nvidia Gforce 940m.
Added the PPA graphics-drivers, and installed nvidia 370, then 367, then 364 (after uninstalling the previous).
But none of them worked. I went to the BIOS and disabled Secure Boot.

But the Drivers DO NOT show in the "Additional Drivers" section. Any help?

Comment: In Windows, does your laptop have or seen something like "Hybrid Graphics"?

Comment: Not sure, where can I find that? The device does have intel and nvidia drivers. My issue now is that after finding and installing the nvidia drivers, I cannot see them in the "additional driver's" section. Even after disabling secure boot...